# How can I , using Numpy, compute how many entries in my array that gives the cumulative sum of 0,9 as an example?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

After preforming PCA I have my (rescaled and proportion of variance explained) array with the sum 1. 
I have to many components to get a good screeplot - therefore I would like to be able to somehow set the desired cumulative sum and get how many of the components of the array I will need to get it. 
As an example `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I wanted the cumulative sum of 6 I'd get the answer that I'd need four entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution would be to use `numpy.cumsum` together with `numpy.where`:

```
arr = np.arange(6) # dummy data
max_cum = 6 # your stop certerion

arr_cum = arr.cumsum() # calculate cumulative sums of your array
num = np.where(arr_cum >= max_cum) # get indices where arr_cum passes your max_cum

>> In: num[0][0]

>> Out:
3
```

`num` contains all indices which contain values that are equal to or higher than your stop criterion, so you will need to fetch the first one (`numpy.where` returns a 2D-array, so you will need `[0][0]`).

One-liner function:

```
def lowest_cum(arr, max_cum):
    return np.where(arr.cumsum() >= max_cum)[0][0]

>> In: lowest_cum(arr=np.arange(6), max_cum=6)

>> Out:
3
```

Edit: needless to say that you need +1 for the number of entries, as the function will return the first index at which the cumsum is completed, so index 3 means 4 entries.

Comment: I didn't get the one-liner to work but the code above worked like a charm. Thanks! Or should I say: Tack så mycket!

Comment: You can call the function like `lowest_cum(arr=np.arange(6), max_cum=6)`

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the cummulative sum, and then calculate the `.argmax(..)` where it is greater than or equal to the threshold:

```
>>> np.argmax(np.hstack((a.cumsum() >= 6, True))) + 1
4
```

Since `a.cumsum()` is the cummulative sum, and thus:

```
>>> a.cumsum()
array([ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10, 15])
```

and we thus calculate the first index where the threshold is satisfied:

```
>>> a.cumsum() >= 6
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

We append a `True`, such that in case there is no equence satisfying the threshold, it will return the number of elements *plus* one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a` is already sorted, simply count the number of entries which do **not** yet exceed the threshold, and add the final entry which does.

```
a = np.arange(6)
num = (a.cumsum() < 6).sum() + 1 # 4
```

As a function:

```
def cum_thresh(a, thresh):
    """
    the sequence a has to be sorted
    """
    return (np.cumsum(a) < thresh).sum() + 1
```